# Python - Installing from forked GitHub repo

Tags: python, git, github, pip, pytextrank

I am trying to install the package found here:

https://github.com/xang1234/pytextrank

Which is a forked repo from `pip3 install pytextrank`.

I have scoured this website, which offers different solutions and nothing seems to work for me:

I.e. I have tried:

```
pip3 install -e git+git://https://github.com/xang1234/pytextrank.git#egg=whatever

pip3 install https://github.com/xang1234/pytextrank
```

And some other variants. If I don't use egg, I get an error about using eggs, and then if I add a random egg I get errors like:

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 128:
```

I am a tad confused about what to do, any advice would be helpful. Thank you

Comment: I assume you tried `pip3 install git+https://github.com/xang1234/pytextrank.git`? Or `pip3 install git+https://github.com/xang1234/pytextrank.git@9717e0c098b91f6b8c02b4e084493e20b195df29`?

Comment: Hey, thank you, those two run but weirdly, import xang_1234_pytextrank as pyt says 'no module named...'. I will look into it, but thank you!

Comment: There's a new release v1.2.1 for the main `pytextrank` package  https://pypi.org/project/pytextrank/ which this one had forked.

Comment: Thank you, I'll check it out when I'm back at work